# How to display the data which i have now in my result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Video.css';

class Video extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.sortIT = this.sortIT.bind(this);
        this.state = { isHide : false};
        this.state = { isResult:[]};
        this.state = { isShow : true}
    }
    sortIT(){
        const finalItVideos = [] 
        this.setState({isHide:true});
        videoList.map((video,i)=>{
            const videosOfIT = video;
            const keyOfVideo = video.key;
            if(keyOfVideo === "IT"){    
                finalItVideos.push(videosOfIT);
            }
        })
        this.setState({isShow : false});
        this.setState({isResult:finalItVideos})
    }


    render(){
        const  hideClass = this.state.isHide ? "hide" : "show";
        const result = this.state.isResult;
        const showClass = this.state.isShow ? "hide" : "show";

        return(

            <div>
            {result}
            <div id="videoContainer" className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            |<br /><b>  Our Videos</b><br />
            <b>You Looking for ?</b>
            <p onClick={this.sortIT}>IT Industry</p>
            <p>Lean Canvas</p>
            <p>Wedding Invitations</p>
            <p>Video Resumes</p>
            <p>App Explainers</p>
            <p>Video Presentations</p>
            <p>Video Campaigns</p>          </div><br />
            <div className={showClass}>
            {this.finalItVideos}
            </div>

            {videoList.map((video, i)=>(
                <div key={i} className={hideClass}>
                {video.images.map((image,index)=>(
                    <VideoItem imageUrl={image} key={index} />
                    ))}
                </div>  
                ))}
            </div>
            <br />
            <button className="btn">
            <i className="fa fa-play fa-rotate-180" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            &nbsp;Load More
            </button>

            </div>
            </div>
            );
    }


}

export default Video;
class VideoItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.imageUrl}
            </div>
            )
    }
}


const videoList = [video Array]
}
]
```

how to display the data in my array the data looks like this

```
{
    key: "Birthday",
    images: [<div name="IT"  className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div className="content">
    <div className="content-overlay"></div>
    <img className="content-image" src={require('./139923200.PNG')} />
    <div className="content-details fadeIn-top">
    <h3>This is a title</h3>
    <a data-fancybox href="https://vimeo.com/139923200?autoplay=1&HD=1"><h4><i className="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    &nbsp;Click To Play</h4></a></div></div>
    </div>]
}
```

and i have three of those in my result array and if i use map its saying map is not defined and if i put it directly this is the error

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, images}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

how to get with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rewriting the state 3 times in the constructor. You should do this:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.sortIT = this.sortIT.bind(this);
        this.state = { isHide : false, isResult:[], isShow : true};
}
```

Now you can do the isResult.map() because the isResult is at least an empty array and you won't have the map error.

Comment: and i have one more like how to load react components onScroll ?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You were getting an error because in the 1st render you had no empty array to map. cheers!